# Does anyone do Test Tracking / Management in SFDC?

Tags: unit-test

Does anyone do their Test Tracking / Test Case Management in SFDC?
If so do you use one of the apps from the app exchange or did you roll your own?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify?  I am not following your question...

Comment: There are App's on the exchange, do you have a use case?

Comment: This is for a QA department.  We use Jira or Pivotal for project tracking / defect management (bug work) however currently we track our tests in spreadsheets.  
Similar software out there would be things like TestRail, TestLodge or Seapine, however I want to use SFDC if possible.  Just curious if anyone else has a similar experience or story.

Answer (score 2):

We use Jira and connect it with SF.  Works fairly well and provides a good communication and information share between our sales/support teams and our engineering team.  Its not free, and I'm sure there are many other options, but I would check it out.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.customware.plugins.connector.salesforce.salesforce-connector-plugin

Comment: Thanks, yes we use Jira for issue tracking, project management, I am looking at the Test management side of the process though.